# Можно ли создать неподписанный .ipa для ios на .NET MAUI?

Tags: ios, maui

Я пытался искать информацию в интернете, но там был только способ для того, чтобы сделать .ipa для AppStore, а для этого нужен платный аккаунт разработчика и сертификаты для подписи приложения. Я брал [от туда](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4397) команду:

```
dotnet publish -f:net7.0-ios -c:Release /p:ServerAddress={macOS build host IP address} /p:ServerUser={macOS username} /p:ServerPassword={macOS password} /p:TcpPort=58181 /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory=/Users/{macOS username}/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/
```

Но терминал выдал мне такую ошибку:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\16.4.7067\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.Publish.targets(22,3): error : A runtime identifier for a device architecture must be specified in order to publish this project. 'iossimulator-x64' is a simulator architecture.
```

Я всё делал по той инструкции и надеялся, что у меня получиться сделать .ipa без сертификатов, но ничего не вышло.
Тогда я достал из iOS симулятора своё приложение **mauiapp.app** и поместил его в созданную папку **Payload**, затем сделал из неё **.zip архив** и поменял расширение с **.zip** на **.ipa**, а потом отправил этот файл своему другу на тест, но после установки приложения iOS выдала сообщение:

```
 Необходимо обновить "{название приложения}"
 Это приложение должно быть обновлено разработчиком для работы под управлением этой версии iOS.
```

А я то думал, что всё получиться...
У друга **iPhone 14 Pro Max** с **iOS 16.3.1**, а минимальная требуемая версия iOS для работы приложения стоит на **iOS 11.0**.
Наверное, это из-за того, что это .app была создана именно под симулятор, а под реальное устройство оно не рассчитано.
Надо отметить, что та неудачная попытка создания .ipa через терминал была сделана на Windows, на MacOS я не пробовал, но думаю, что будет так же.
Так возможно ли вообще создать неподписанный .ipa?

Comment: Первая [ссылка гугла](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1136733/vs-2022-for-mac-publish-issue), пробовали?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так смысл от этого, если там всё равно нужны сертификаты подписи, а для них нужен платный аккаунт разработчика. Я же спрашиваю про то, можно ли каким-нибудь образом сделать .ipa файл без всяких сертификатов. При сборке для андройда сразу делается .apk, который можно использовать на любом устройстве и никакие сертификаты не нужны. А вот как сделать так же для iOS?

Comment: Я ваш вопрос расцениваю больше как "Собираю так, получаю ошибку, как в итоге собрать?". Вот почему эта ошибка, и как ее решить, я вам дал ссылку выше. Ну а про аккаунт, на сколько я знаю Apple это требует, и обойти нельзя. Сборка проекта только на официальной макс оси и только с нужным акком.